# How to allow a normal user to kill a certain root application in visudo with no password

Tags: linux, kill

I wanna allow a normal user to kill a certain application which is started by root user.

In visudo:

I added a line like this:

```
normal_user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/kill $(ps aux | grep 'target_application' | awk '{print $2}')
```

But after save it and execute the following command as normal_user, I still get the prompt for root password:

```
sudo /usr/bin/kill $(ps aux | grep 'target_application' | awk '{print $2}')
```

What should I do then? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think it could be better to add this option into a script and in sudoers allow user to run it without password.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sudo will not interpret the command as a shell script to execute.  Therefore you have said that this literal command can be run as normal_user:

```
/usr/bin/kill $(ps aux | grep 'target_application' | awk '{print $2}')
```

However since the shell will interpret the stuff in the `$(...)` before sudo is called on it, the command you are running looks more like this:

```
sudo /usr/bin/kill 1234
```

So it doesn't let you use it.

As fedorqui suggested, you should write a script that kills the user and then give normal_user the right to run that script (make sure they don't have write access to the script or its directory though).

kill_target_application.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/kill $(ps aux | grep 'target_application' | awk '{print $2}')
```

Use this command to allow users to execute or read the script, but not modify it:

```
chown root:root <filename>
chmod 755 <filename>
```

The give (r)ead and e(x)ecute permissions for all users, but only root can modify it.  Also ensure that the user does not have write permissions for the directory or any of its parent directories.  Read the chown and chmod man pages before doing this if you aren't familiar with these utilities.

visudo entry:

```
normal_user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /path/to/kill_target_application.sh
```

You should probably use "killall" instead of this complicated ps | grep option.  Or at least look into pgrep.

Also, this really sounds like a job for an init script.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! Indeed, I am trapped in this issue because my original approach is also to leave it in an external script. However, this means if the normal_user changes the content of the script, he will be able to do anything he wants... which is really bad...

Comment: So you ensure that the user does not have write access to the script or the directory.

Comment: In macOS `no such file or directory: /usr/bin/kill`